# Android Rect intersetcs method (to check collision)

Tags: android, collision

I am trying to get 2 rectangles to check collision but I cant succeed, I even created them on top of  each other yet no luck.

```
int testrectX = 0 ;
public Rect testRect = new Rect(testrectX, 500, testrectX +1, 400);
public Rect testRect2 = new Rect(testrectX, 500, testrectX +1, 400);


    if (Rect.intersects(testRect, testRect2)) {

        System.out.println("testRect intersects with testRect1");

}
```

Comment: bottom is less than top... maybe that´s the problem...

Comment: `x` and `y` grow from top left of the screen... so `bottom` means a `y` bigger than the initial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some of the documentation on the constructor you used.

> [public Rect (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html)
>
> Create a new rectangle with the specified coordinates. Note: no range checking is performed, so the caller must ensure that left <= right and top <= bottom.

As eduyayo commented, you created rectangles with top > bottom, and I believe Rect.intersects identifies them as empty rectangles with empty intersections. Try making sure the rectangles are constructed to be nonempty.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I missed this

fixed by making top smaller then bottom

```
public Rect testRect = new Rect(testrectX, 300, testrectX +1, 400);
public Rect testRect2 = new Rect(testrectX, 300, testrectX +1, 400);
```